# VSCode support with JSHint and JSCS

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi I want to  to use JSHint and JSCS with VSCode so does vscode support jshint and jscs packages out of the box. or do we have the option of using it from node command prompt.
Regards
MS

Answer (score 5):

It is already possible. Given that VSCode is now open for extensions, JSHint and JSCS are available through third party extensions, of course, Node.js is required.

You can check a post that I've written about the installation of those extensions. It's here: [Installing JSHint and JSCS in Visual Studio Code](http://avillenas.com/post/installing-jshint-and-jscs-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, no, but easy to get: go to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode/Linters and you'll see two extensions - which can be installed together - for both jshint and jscs. These use your .jshintrc and .jscsrc, if any, in your repo/workspace.